# How to create input with specific value layout?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a date picker with a `<input type="text"/>` element. Because of specific reasons I cannot use the common `<input type="date" />` element. In my input I want that the user is able to type in his date of birth in the following format: dd.MM.YYYY

Is there any possibility to create a "pre-defined" value of the input? I mean I'd like to have 2 . (dot) characters in my input value, which the user cannot delete. So one dot at `index[3]` of the date string and one dot at `index[6]` of the date string (`XX.XX.XXXX`).

Comment: Add some code to create context.
cmd+M or ctrl + M

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: also limit the characters:

```css
.day, .month{
  width: 25px;
}
.year{
 width:40px; 
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" placeholder="DD" class="day" maxlength="2">.
  <input type="text" placeholder="MM" class="month"maxlength="2">.
  <input type="text" placeholder="YYYY" class="year"maxlength="4">
```

Comment: Not very user friendly